# Python - Append to beginning of QueryDict - keeping order to convert to query string

Tags: python, query-string, urlencode, urllib

I am trying to add to beginning of a QueryDict and maintain the order of the items (needing to eventually encode into a query string with a particular order).  I know that a querydict is immutable, and so you have to .copy() first, but can't seem to add the value.  You can tell by my log that the querydict doesn't change.  Thanks for any hints you can give-

Here is my Python code:

```
if self.request.POST:
    params = self.request.POST.copy()

logging.info('params response back: %s' % params)   

if params:
    params['cmd']='_notify-validate'  
    logging.info('just added cmd: %s' % params)             
    params = urllib.urlencode(params)
    logging.info('converted response back: %s' % params)
```

Here is my log:

```
2014-07-03 10:58:36.460 params response back: UnicodeMultiDict([('residence_country', u'US'), ('invoice', u'abc1234'), ('address_city', u'San Jose'), ('first_name', u'John'),

2014-07-03 10:58:36.461 just added cmd: UnicodeMultiDict([('residence_country', u'US'), ('invoice', u'abc1234'), ('address_city', u'San Jose'), ('first_name', u'John'), ('pay

2014-07-03 10:58:36.462 converted response back: residence_country=US&invoice=abc1234&address_city=San+Jose&first_name=John&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&mc_fee=0.44&txn_id=53760294
```

Comment: Minor quibble: "appending to the beginning" is known as prepending. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use (name,value) pair tuples to ensure order instead of a dict (which by definition cannot guarantee any order, and in fact has no order)

```
params = urllib.urlencode([("param1","val1"),("param2","val2"),...])
```

this will guarantee the order of params

Comment: I am having to start with a QueryDict (comes from PayPal's notification), so how would I change that to tuples -- and prepend a value? -Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

QueryDict inherits from Django's MultiValueDict which inherits from Python's dict which is implemented as a hash table. Thus, you can't guarantee it will stay ordered.

But what you can do is add the keys only to a list to preserve that ordering (while minimizing the space).